# head.js throwing property js not found errors

Tags: javascript

Chrome throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'js' of object function
>   (){d.ready.apply(null,arguments)} is not a function

While Firefox throws a `TypeError: head.js is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="eng" ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/0.99/head.core.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
    head.js({ angularJS:   "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"},
            { jQuery:      "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" },
            { internalApp: "app/js/app.js"});

    head.ready('jQuery', function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('jQuery loaded successfully');
        });
    });
    </script>

    <body>
        <!-- add data here -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your `<script>` is in no-mans-land. Either put it in the `<head>` or in the `<body>`, not in between; that doesn't make sense.

Comment: how would that affect my code?

Comment: I figured that might get rid of the error but I guess it doesn't? `head.js` isn't a function, are you sure you're using `head` right?

Comment: Yeah. http://headjs.com/

Comment: I'd almost say the library is broken. Try running a non minified version, maybe you get a better error.

Answer (score 5):

You have loaded the Responsive Design + Feature Detections script http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/1.0.3/head.core.min.js and not the Asset Loader http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/1.0.3/head.load.min.js

I just made the same mistake and found this post while looking up the answer :)